# Apache does not load PDO SQLSRV drivers ERROR: 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, apache, pdo

I am trying to add the PDO drivers so I can work with MSSQL

I get error 'could not find driver'. In my php.ini I have tried adding

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll
```

But my phpinfo() shows no sqlsrv in PDO, only mysql and sqlite

- My PHP Version : 5.3.9
- Compiler : MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)

Comment: For the records: `Compiler : MSVC9` means that you need `_vc9.dll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my own answer...

My php.ini file that was loaded was not from

```
    wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\php.ini
```

but from

```
    wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.21\php.ini
```